# Cannot start Apache with public ip address

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to start the apache server and it works with localhost and port 80.
When I change the localhost to the public IP address and run
`sudo systemctl start httpd`

I am geting: `Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Same error with port 8080.

I am using RedHat Oracle Linux.

systemctl status:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since пет 2021-12-24 10:05:50 GMT; 30min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 16641 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 12998 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25587 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 25587 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTT...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 httpd[25587]: (99)Cannot assign req...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 httpd[25587]: no listening sockets ...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 httpd[25587]: AH00015: Unable to op...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 systemd[1]: httpd.service: main pro...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apa...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service ente...
дец 24 10:05:50 instance-20211223-1319 systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Did you had a look at `"systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe"`

Comment: I added `systemctl status httpd.service` to the question

Comment: *" When I change the localhost to the public IP address"*  - How are you doing that? Because the usual default is to use [`Listen 80`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) and then Apache httpd will listen *all* interfaces and you don't do anything special for localhost or your public interfaces. Note that if you create overlapping Listen directives that will result in a fatal error which will prevent the server from starting up.

Comment: @Bob I changed `Listen 80` to `Listen ip_address:80` and it doesn't work, When I use `Listen 80` it works, but can I connect to Apache server with public IP using `Listen 80`?

Comment: When I tried to connect remotely I got: "The server at is_address is taking too long to respond."

Comment: Is the public address assigned to your server directly, or is it assigned to a router doing NAT? In other words, do you see the public address in `ip -br a` or not?

Comment: I cannot si that public address in `ip -br a` I copied current address from Cloud as public address

Comment: ip -br a shows ip address but port is different then 80